# Why can't I access NavController.getCurrentBackStackEntry()?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-mvvm, android-jetpack-navigation

On the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/NavController#getcurrentbackstackentry) it is listed as a public method that I should be able to use. However, it does not appear as a choice when I use the dot operator on my NavController field neither as a method or property. Can't get it to work on the debugger expression evaluator either. I can confirm my object is of type androidx.navigation.NavController

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Navigation `2.3.0-alpha02` release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.3.0-alpha02):

> Convenience methods of `getCurrentBackStackEntry()` and `getPreviousBackStackEntry()` have been added to make it easier to retrieve a `NavBackStackEntry` for the current and previous destinations. ([b/79672220](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79672220))

So make sure you upgrade to Navigation `2.3.0-alpha02`.

Comment: (Note that this is specifically called out at the top of the [Returning a result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result) page, which uses that method)

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! I was on 2.2.1. Btw great talks over and Android developers!

Comment: Is there any way to use 2.2.2 the latest stable release and still get the functionality of these API's?

Comment: @MobDev - you'd need to upgrade (currently to `2.3.0-beta01`) if you want to use new APIs added in that release. That's kind of the whole point of having new releases.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I ended up using a work out until 2.3 is stable. You can use ```getBackStackEntry(navController.getCurrentDestination().getId()``` and ```getParent``` in some common situations.